# Compact representation of OpenGL modelview matrix 4x4

Tags: c, opengl, 3d, matrix, rotation

What is the most user friendly way to store only the rotation part of an OGL modelview (4x4) matrix?

For example; in a level editor to set the rotation for an object it would be easy to use the XYZ Euler angles. However this seems a very tricky system to use with matrices.

I need to be able to get AND set the rotation from this new representation.

(The alternative is to store the rotation part (4*3 numbers) but it is hard for a user to manipulate these)

I found some code here http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#HQY9Wd_snmY/mesh/matrix3.h&q=matrix3&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc that allows me to set and get rotation from angles (3 floats). This is ideal.

Comment: The rotation part is 3x3, not 4x3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although they're used regularily, I disregard the use of Euler angles. They're problematic as they only preserve the pointing direction of the object, but not the bitangent to that direction. More important: They're prone to gibal lock http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock

A far superior method for storing rotations are **Quarternions**. In layman terms a quaternion consists of the rotational axis and the angle of rotation around this axis. It is thus a tuple of 4 scalars a,b,c,d. The quaternion is then Q = a + i*b + j*c + k*d, |Q| = 1, with the special properties of i,j,k that i² = j² = k² = i·j·k = -1 and i·j = k, j·k = i, k·i = j, which implies j·i = -k, k·j = -i, i·k = -j

Quaterions are thus extensions of complex numbers. If you recall complex number theory, you'll remember that the product of two complex numbers a =/= b with |a| = |b| = 1 is a rotation in the complex plane. It is thus easy to assume that rotations in 3D can be described by an extension of complex numbers into a complex hyperplane. This is what quaternions are.

See this article on the details.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Comment: gah, you got me by one minute. Deleting my answer :D

Comment: BTW, you should mention that generating the quaternion from the user-generated rotation axis and angle is trivial...

Answer (score 1):

I would say this depends on the user, but to me the most "user friendly" way is to store "roll", "pitch" and "yaw".  These are very non-technical terms that an average user can understand and adjust, and it should be easy for you to take these values and compute the matrix.

Comment: I can set the rotation matrix to yaw pitch roll values easily but I can't find out how to get them from the matrix

Comment: @tm1rbrt i've edited the answer to show one possible way of obtaining these values

Comment: oops i just realized my edit was completely flawed -- removed it :)

Answer (score 1):

In a standard 3D matrix you only need the top left 3x3 values to give the rotation.  To apply the matrix as a 4x4 later on, you need to make the other values 0 apart from on the diagonal.

Here's a rotation only matrix where the values vXY give the rotations.

```
[v00 v01 v02  0]
[v10 v11 v12  0]
[v20 v21 v22  0]
[  0   0   0  1]
```

Interestingly, the values form the bases of the coordinate system you have rotated the object into, so in the new system, the x-axis is along [v00 v01 v02], the y-axis is along [v10 v11 v12] and the z-axis obviously [v20 v21 v22].

You could show these axes beside the object and let the other drag them around to change the rotation, perhaps.

Comment: I like this but its hard to input values manually (for example from text)

Comment: Ok, I thought maybe you had some sort of mouse UI for it.  Sure, typing and understanding 9 values isn't easy..

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the most 'user friendly format' for rotation is storing Euler XYZ angles, this is generally how rotations are exposed in any 3d content creation software.

Euler angles are easy to transform to matrices, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_representation_%28mathematics%29#Conversion_formulae_between_representations) for the involved matrix product.

*But* you should not confuse the format given to the GUI/user and the storage format of the data: Euler XYZ angles have problems of their own when doing animation, [gimbal lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock) can introduce unwanted behaviour.

Another candidate for storing/computing rotations is [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation). They offer mathematical advantages over XYZ angles, essentially when interpolating between two rotations. Of course, you don't want to expose the quaternion values directly to any human user, you'll need to convert them to XYZ angles. You'll find plenty of code to that on the Web.

I would not recommend storing the rotation directly in matrix format. Extracting user friendly values from it is difficult, it does not offer any interesting behaviour for animation/interpolation, it takes for storage. IMO, matrices are to be created when needed to transform the geometry.

To conclude, there are a few options, you should select what suits you most. Do you plan to having animation or not ? etc.

*EDIT*
Also, you should not make an amalgam with model and view matrices. They are semantically very different, and are combined in OpenGL only for performance reasons. What I had in mind above in the 'model matrix'. The view matrix is generally given by your view system/camera manager, and is combined with you model matrix.

Answer (score 0):

A quaternion is, although the math is "obscure and unintellegible" surprisingly user friendly, as it represents rotation around an axis by a given angle.

The axis of rotation is simply a unit vector pointing in that direction, multiplied by the sine of 1/2 the rotation angle, and the "obscure" 4th component equals the cosine of 1/2 the rotation angle.

It feels kind of "unnatural" at first sight, but once you grasp it... can it be any easier?